# mnist's deep feature visualizations is nothing

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, deconvolution

when I used [yosinski/deep-visualization-toolbox](https://github.com/yosinski/deep-visualization-toolbox) to visualize the conv feature of [mnist](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt), I found that the deconv feature is nothing, the left-bottom of the picture
[image]
but the visualization of imagenet is what I want to see

[image]

so I am wondering what the problem is? the toolbox's visualization problem or the special thing of mnist's feature?

Answer (score 1):

I use [darkon](https://github.com/darkonhub/darkon) to visualize, it looks good

[image]

top is heatmap, bottom is feature map

when feed a noise image, the net get a wrong label '5', we can see that the heatmap and feature map get a wrong location:

[image]